# I have a text file which having some data line by line.arated.I want to read th line by line and store the field values using Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using spool file path I can read but how to proceed next for reading line by line and splitting it using pipeline .each row in text file having 3 values separated by pipeline.

I want to split each line by pipeline and store those values in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using SQL Developer Command Line (SQLcl) from https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/sqlcl/download/ It is compatible with SQL*Plus plus and has some extra features. You can load your data with with the LOAD command. Since your data is delimited with pipe (|) you need to change the loadformat:

```
set loadformat delimited |
```

Then load your file foo.csv into table foo with:

```
load foo foo.csv
```